# Visual Studio Web Installer installing to local source control folder instead of inetpub?

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2013, windows-installer

I'm using the [VS2013 Installer extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d) to build a web service installer.

The problem I'm having is that after installing this service, if I go to the inetpub folder, I find no reference to the service I just installed, and the service is evidently installed in the local source folder instead.

This behaviour is consistent regardless of where the installer is run from on the HDD.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtlZi.gif]

If anyone has any insight on this, I'd appreciate it. I assumed that the installation directory would be determined based on the inetpub folder used by the Default Web Site, but it doesn't appear to be.